# Excel function for SUMIF (RIGHT = RIGHT)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

It's probably a quick one, but I'm desperate...

How can I put 2 corresponding `RIGHT` functions into a `SUMIF`? Or does this need VBA?

**The case:**
I want the sum of B:B, if any cell of J:J has the same last 4 numbers as A1.

**EDIT**
Column J shows the date an invoice was payed (e.g. "14. November 2020"). A1 is the headline and includes "Income 2020".
The sum in B14 should show how much money came in in the year the sheet is representing.

```
SUMIF(RIGHT(J:J;4);RIGHT(A1;4);B:B)
```

May someone enlighten me?
Thanks a lot!
Thomas

Comment: Do you have some sample data and expected outcome please? Just to picture what it is exactly you are after.

Comment: Sure, one moment.

Comment: If column `J` contains actual dates, then use `SUMIFS`: `=SUMIFS(B:B;J:J;">="&Date(RIGHT($A$1;4);1;1);J:J;"<="&Date(RIGHT($A$1;4);12;31))`.

Comment: See edit. Understandable?

Comment: Not sure if these are true dates as per @BigBen has mentioned. If pure text, and you want to know how to check the last four characters against a single cell, then maybe try: `=SUMPRODUCT((RIGHT(J:J,4)=RIGHT(A1,4))*B:B)`. If one has ExcelO365 I guess you could also use `FILTER`. Please show some actual sample data.

Comment: @BigBen Yeah, but then I would have to alter the code for every year and if users would just have to change the Headline they could do it themselves without having to change the function.

Comment: @Touminator - changed the formula to use `RIGHT` instead of the hard-coded year.

Comment: Just enter your formula as array-formula. It should work. Enter the formula with `Ctrl`+ `Shift` + `Enter` instead of the normal way (just `Enter`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If column J contains true dates, then you can use `SUMIFS` and `DATE`:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B;J:J;">="&DATE(RIGHT($A$1;4);1;1);J:J;"<="&DATE(RIGHT($A$1;4);12;31))
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't working because the value in column J is a date. You should use SUMIFS and use a date range.

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,J:J,">="&DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),1,1),B:B,"<="&DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),12,31))
```

Comment: Why post a duplicate of the accepted answer? Except you got it wrong, the second `B:B` should be `J:J`.